# How return specific column from table and asoociation table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, associations

I have two models:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, class_name: 'Comment', foreign_key: 
  'comment_id'
 end

=> Comment(id: integer, text: string, user_id: integer, product_id: 
integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, comment_id: 
integer)

class User < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = 'users'
  has_many :comments
end

=> User(id: integer, username: string)
```

how can i return `text` and `username` throgh comment object.

For example `c = Comment.limit(2)` => `c.map { |a| hash << c.text, hash << c.user['username']}`. I want return comments texts and username for each comment. Tell me if you dont understang. TY

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?